# Instalar paquetes automáticamente antes de iniciar programa

Tags: python, python-3.x

Soy relativamente nuevo programando y hace poco finalicé mi primer programa "serio" y me gustaría que un amigo lo probase. El asunto es que para ejecutar el programa se necesitan descargar ciertos paquetes primero y me gustaría que al ejecutar el programa este detecte si dichos paquetes están instalados y de no estarlos que estos se descarguen automáticamente para que luego el programa se ejecute correctamente.

La idea es que mi amigo solo descargue python y luego pueda ejecutar el programa sin necesidad de descargar los paquetes manualmente. Hay alguna forma de lograr esto?

Cualquier link que contenga información al respecto también me serviría de mucho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a suponer que usas virtualenv (si no lo usas, mira este enlace para hacerte una idea de porqué deberías usarlo: https://codeday.me/es/qa/20190320/329809.html), porque si no, esto se complicaría mucho.

1. Si tu amigo no tiene mucha idea de Python, puedes optar por:

   - generar un ejecutable con [PyInstaller](https://www.pyinstaller.org/) o [Py2Exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) y simplemente sea doble click. Eso si, si es para Windows, deberás generar el ejecutable desde Windows, y viceversa con Unix.
   - También puedes optar por: Generar un `requirements.txt` con `pip freeze > requirements.txt` y en tu código Python y al comienzo de tu programa, usando [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.system), hacer algo así:

```
try:
    import paquete
    #etc
except:
    # Creas el virtualenv para no llenar su ordenador de basura
    os.system('python3 -m virtualenv venv')
    # Entras en el virtualenv
    os.system('source venv/bin/activate')
    # Instalas los paquetes
    os.system('pip install -r requirements.txt')
# Al final del programa deberías hacer esto para salir del virtualenv
os.system('deactivate')
```

2. Si tu amigo tiene idea de Python, puedes optar por: Generar un `requirements.txt` con `pip freeze > requirements.txt` y así sacar el listado de tus paquetes instalados. Pasarle a tu amigo el .py y el requirements.txt y que los instale con `pip install -r requirements.txt`